# Error on adding image to gridview windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I am trying to add images that I get from my webcam to gridview however each time I get exception. I have separate page to make a picture from webcam and later, I pass image full path to other page. Here are the code snippets:

**C#**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //If navigated from PhotoCapturePage
    if (m_ToBeNavigatedPageType == typeof(PhotoCapturePage))
    {
        if (e.Parameter == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = 64;
        img.Height = 64;
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e.Parameter.ToString()));

        IncidentPictures.Add(img);

        IncidentPictureGrid.Items.Add(img);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding IncidentPictures}" Name="IncidentPictureGrid" Width="350"></GridView>
```

Each time `IncidentPictureGrid.Items.Add(img)` is performed, I receive Catastrophic failure `(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))` exception.
Does anyone has suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Miroslawas

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add the image to the Grid.Items collection when you add it to IncidentPictures collection too?

You already bind the GridView's ItemsSource to the collection. Maybe this cause the error ... Remove the IncidentPictureGrid.Items.Add and make sure, that IncidentPictures is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: It does not make any difference.

Comment: Ok, so the error occured when IncidentPictureGrid.Items.Add(img) was performed. If you remove that line, it occures on IncidentPictures.Add(img)?